# no automatically word wrap with bibliography

Tags: latex, biblatex

I have a problem with my `biblatex`. My booktitles don't automaticly break lines in my bibliography. Has someone got a hint how to solve this? Is it possible to get an automatic break or do I have to set them manually? And if I so, how do I do that?

Here my biblatex code snippets:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
```

See this example at IEEE: after Metrics is a linebreak is missing.

[image: biblio screeny]

**EDIT**: I found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104058/getting-emph-back-to-normal-after-loading-ulem)

I was curious about the \emph{} style (mine was always underlining). I put a single \normalem in front of the \printbibliography command and it works fine :)

```
\normalem
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
```

Comment: For future reference, ask (La)TeX-related question on [tex.se].

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I have to hand in my thesis in a few hours and this was NOT  something I wanted to have to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book titles are underlined, which is preventing line breaks (underlined text doesn't break). I don't think this is a standard behavior, book titles are usually displayed in italics. Perhaps you are using `\underline{}` inside your bibliography items definitions?

Comment: hi miguel, thanks for the inside :) i didn't know that. 
I guess that the bibliography uses \emph{} and mine is underlining instead of using italic. Someone know how to change that?